# Gradle not working with android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

[image: screen]

I've tried everything I've found on the ointernet with all the error messages i found. Styles are missing, gradle can't sync and nothing is working. Help please

**build.gradle** (Project:MyApplication)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle** (module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.utente.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: Please show the contents of your build.gradle

Comment: Post your app/build.gradle file

Comment: from the image: `method not found: maven()`. You can try clicking the link "gradle settings"